# Migrating from AForge.NET to OpenCV in .NET Core for Rectangle Detection in Images

Tags: c#, opencv, .net-core

I'm in the process of porting a .NET Framework application to .NET Core, specifically moving from a Windows environment to Linux. My application involves analyzing and processing images of PV modules, including tasks like autoleveling, normalizing, and detecting the largest rectangle to isolate the PV module.

Originally, the application used AForge.net for image processing, which isn't compatible with my current setup due to the lack of `System.Drawing` on Linux. I've switched to using OpenCV with MagickImage for initial image processing, but I'm encountering issues with the rectangle detection that AForge.net handled well.

Here's the original AForge.net code used for detecting the rectangle:

```cs
var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);

// Step 1 - turn background to black
var colorFilter = new ColorFiltering
{
    Red = new IntRange(0, 64),
    Green = new IntRange(0, 64),
    Blue = new IntRange(0, 64),
    FillOutsideRange = false
};
colorFilter.ApplyInPlace(bitmapData);

// Step 2 - locating objects
var blobCounter = new BlobCounter
{
    FilterBlobs = true,
    MinHeight = bitmap.Size.Height / 2,
    MinWidth = bitmap.Size.Width / 2
};
blobCounter.ProcessImage(bitmapData);
var blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

List<IntPoint> corners = null;
for (int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++)
{
    List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);
    corners = PointsCloud.FindQuadrilateralCorners(edgePoints);
}
```

And here's my attempt at replicating this functionality with OpenCV in .NET Core:

```cs
// Convert Magick.NET image to byte array
byte[] pixelBytes = image.GetPixels().ToByteArray(PixelMapping.RGB);

// Create OpenCV Mat from byte array
Mat opencvImage = new Mat(image.Height, image.Width, MatType.CV_8UC3, pixelBytes);

// Convert the image to grayscale and apply GaussianBlur
Mat gray = new Mat();
Cv2.CvtColor(opencvImage, gray, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
Cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, gray, new Size(5, 5), 0);
Cv2.Threshold(gray, gray, 0, 255, ThresholdTypes.Otsu);

// Find contours
Point[][] contours;
HierarchyIndex[] hierarchy;
Cv2.FindContours(gray, out contours, out hierarchy, RetrievalModes.List, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);

if (contours.Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No contours found.");
    return; // Adjust based on your method's return type
}

RotatedRect largestRectangle = new RotatedRect();
double maxArea = 0;
double minAreaThreshold = (image.Width * image.Height) / 4;

foreach (var contour in contours)
{
    Point[] approx = Cv2.ApproxPolyDP(contour, Cv2.ArcLength(contour, true) * 0.02, true);
    if (approx.Length == 4 && Cv2.IsContourConvex(approx))
    {
        double area = Cv2.ContourArea(approx);
        if (area > minAreaThreshold && area > maxArea)
        {
            maxArea = area;
            largestRectangle = Cv2.MinAreaRect(approx);
        }
    }
}

// Convert RotatedRect to Point array
Point2f[] rectPoints = largestRectangle.Points();

// Convert Point2f to Point (required for drawing function)
Point[] points = rectPoints.Select(p => new Point((int)p.X, (int)p.Y)).ToArray();

// Draw the rectangle on the original image
Cv2.Polylines(opencvImage, new[] { points }, true, Scalar.Red, 2);
```

However, the results from OpenCV are not as accurate as I hoped. While some corners of the detected rectangle align well, others do not, leading to inaccurate isolation of the PV module. Here's an example image showing the issue:

[image: image_after_opencv]

**Question**: How can I improve the rectangle detection accuracy with OpenCV to match or exceed the results previously achieved with AForge.net?

**Additional Context**:

- The application is now running on .NET Core under Linux.
- I've ensured that the initial image processing steps (autolevel and normalize) are correctly applied before attempting rectangle detection.
- I am using the OpenVcSharp4 nuget packages (and also Magick.NET)

Any insights or suggestions to improve the accuracy of the rectangle detection

Comment: debug the steps. you should suspect approxPolyDP because it only removes points, it does not do any line fitting or minimum area fitting. -- also: [mre]. please provide source data to reproduce the issue. -- no, I am not set up to build any C# code. if you're asking about OpenCV in general, I am willing to deal with Python code (but not anything I'd have to compile)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to specify which .NET library you will use as an alternative to Aforge.NET and my guess is that you would prefer to use **OpenCvSharp** or **Emgu CV**. I would recommend Emgu CV where you

1. Load the Image into a Mat struct
2. Detect Edges
3. Detect Contours
4. Use `CVInvoke.ApproxPolyDp()` to loop through each contour detected to check if it's a quadrilateral, then you can grab the points and process further to check if they meet your definition of a valid rectangle
5. Use `CVInvoke.Draw()` to draw over the areas on the image where the rectangles were detected

Comment: They didn’t ask for a library recommendation. (And, even if they did, that would be off topic for this site.) They asked how to achieve this specifically in **OpenCV**.

Comment: that answer doesn't even try to answer the question. it just rephrases what OP already stated. -- I've retracted my flag because the mods don't need the help.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, thanks for editing it but you all know that stack Overflow is not a free code writing service even if the OP has a problem he needs to attempt with open CV and then ask us when he gets into trouble